# Firebase Web: How To Redirect User Data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm new to firebase and i'm creating a small multipage site. I got Google Authentication working, but how can i keep a user logged in/transfer user data through-out multiple pages without having to re-login?

Thanks!

Comment: just access firebase.auth() to see auth state

Comment: thanks, but can you be a little more specific? sorry i appreciate it!

Comment: Include the firebase-auth.js on each page and add firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged listener to detect the user being logged in on each page. The auth state should persist as long as you are using the same domain for all your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of your auth state by using `firebase.auth()`, there you can access your `uid` and also `currentUser` which holds email, displayName etc.

To watch the auth state you can use the following snippet:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  alert('Your name is ' + user.displayName);
});
```